# docker container vs swarm communication issue

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-swarm

I have several docker containers that will run together just fine on a single machine.  One binds to port 80, another connects to a neo4j container that is also spun up.  The others are for inter-container work (I didn't build them, but I have to host them).  I have a docker swarm setup with docker engine 1.12 and a progrium/consul cluster across the 3 machines in the swarm.  The consul cluster can see all of the containers, and they work when using just run -d (on each single host as mentioned).  As soon as I put any of them out as a "service", they can no longer communicate.  I've tried creating a new overlay network but it had no impact.

I also tried running the one container that binds to port 80 as an individual container on all of the systems where the others are running as services.  Docker inspect shows them all on the same 172.17.0.0 network.

I could really use some ideas on what to look at.  Thanks.

---

First, I load neo4j with:

```
docker run -d -p 192.168.2.201:7474:7474 \
  --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data neo4j:3.0
```

Then, the subsequent containers are joining a consul cluster on the docker swarm using:

```
docker run -d -e "CONSULJOIN=172.17.0.2" -e "NEO4J_HOST=172.17.0.4" \
  -e "NEO4J_PASSWORD=$NEO4J_PASS" container
```

When instead of `docker run -d` I use `docker create service`, the expectation is that if I replace the neo4j IP with 192.168.2.201, it should work.

I also tried using an overlay network:

```
docker network create -d overlay my-net
```

And included the --net=my-net in the docker service command.  I don't know when I'll have time to debug further, but if this is enough to at least tell me what I did wrong that would be great.  If not, I'll try to get some more info as time permits.

Comment: Please include the commands you're running, including the network and service create commands, and any debugging output.

Comment: So these systems are on internal VMs.  First, I load neo4j with: docker run -d -p 192.168.2.201:7474:7474 --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data neo4j:3.0.  Then, the subsequent containers are joining a consul cluster on the docker swarm using: docker run -d -e "CONSULJOIN=172.17.0.2" -e "NEO4J_HOST=172.17.0.4" -e "NEO4J_PASSWORD=$NEO4J_PASS" container.  When instead of docker run -d I use docker create service, the expectation is that if I replace the neo4j IP with 192.168.2.201, it should work. Sorry, I should also state that while I've been in Linux administration for some time, I'm new to docker.

Comment: I've updated the question with your comment above. Could you also edit with the network create commands you attempted? Under the covers, Docker is creating bridged networks, and controlling access with iptables, so you should be able to use your standard Linux toolset to debug. Connect to a bash shell in any container with `docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash` for further debugging.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I initially tried it without creating a new overlay network then I created one using docker.  I'm adding that command above, and when I started the services I included the --net=my-net part.  I'm actually going to be moving direction into using Kubernetes, so it's not as crucial to get this working, but it would be nice to know where I was going wrong.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You aren't supposed to specify the IP address to find the service on the cluster.  It could be on any machine on the cluster unless you add constraints to place it on a specific machine.

Once you create a network overlay you may then reference the services by container/service name rather than a specific IP address.  For example, work through a simple example before jumping back to your application.

This assumes you have created your swarm cluster already:

**create a network overlay**

```
docker network create --driver overlay my-app-network
```

**start a simple redis service**

```
docker service create --replicas 1 --network my-app-network \
   --name demo-redis redis
```

**create a dummy service that we'll log into for further exploration:**

```
docker service create --replicas 1 --network my-app-network \
--name demo-alpine alpine /bin/sh -c "trap 'exit 0' INT TERM; while true; do echo Hello World; sleep 10; done"
```

**Note:** At this point we've created a container that doesn't really do anything but we'll be logging into it so we can explore interactively to see what is going on.

**find the node the demo-alpine service is running on**

```
docker service ps demo-alpine #this will report which node is running the container
```

**SSH into the node that is running demo-alpine and attach to it's shell**

```
docker ps #lists all the running containers on that node, find the container ID of demo-alpine

docker exec -i -t <container id> /bin/sh

#install python,pip and redis(for python) in your demo-alpine container
apk update
apk add python
apk add py-pip
pip install redis
```

**create a script to hit your redis service by container/service name**
vi test.py and paste something like this:

```
import redis
import time

loopy = True

while loopy == True:
    # I'm creating the connection each time so we can see the change when we scale the Redis service
    # and the new service is brought online; connections should start rotating through the scaled Redis servers.
    # If one uses a Redis connection scoped outside of the loop then it would remain connected to the first Redis
    # service and we wouldn't see the new one come online.

    r = redis.StrictRedis(host='demo-redis', port=6379, db=0)
    r.incr('counter')
    print(r.get('counter'))
    time.sleep(3)
```

**run the script from within your demo-alpine container**

```
python test.py
```

Notice that I've referenced the redis service by its container/service name not by IP, as it could be anywhere on the cluster.  You should start seeing the incremented values print to screen.

For extra fun, if it is working for you, scale the redis service to see it scale to the already running Python script.

**ssh into the manager node from another terminal session so you don't stop your demo-alpine session**

```
docker service scale demo-redis=3
```

You should start seeing new increment values printing to the screen from the newly scaled redis service and the cluster should round-robin requests to each newly created redis service.  Synching that data is another story - but that wasn't the point of the quick demo.

At this point you should be able to go back to your app and get it working on your cluster.  You may have to change your code to reference the container names rather than the IP addresses but that is the point of running it on the cluster; it could be anywhere.

Comment: Thank you! We will be analyzing this and attempting to change how we're doing the call to other containers. I'm old-school, monolith systems guy, so it's just taking a little to wrap my head around the containerized way of doing things.

Comment: My pleasure.  I always appreciate a relatively end-to-end example as it makes it easier to move on afterwards to integrate ones own work after going through a simple example.  Please note that I just fixed a bug in the very last statement that scales the service.  I had originally put the output of the command rather than the command - it is fixed now.  I've also got this written up on my Github account and plan to expand it.  https://github.com/ctownsen357/docker-swarm-demo